# Why is this custom wordpress link not clickable?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Custom top header button "back to cosemi corporate" in wordpress header wont work. Its a normal A href link and should click and send users to page but it does nothing.

See menu here - https://www.cosemi.com/consumer/?cmp_bypass=testingwindow123

```
<div class="back-cosemi-btn">
<a href="https://www.cosemi.com/">BACK TO COSEMI CORPORATE</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like its behind the header element.

Try adding this css

```
.back-cosemi-btn a {
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you so much.